# Using ROUND() with a longer expression SQL

Tags: sql, rounding

I am trying to round the output of a query in SQLite.

Here is the portion of the query I am curious about:

```sql
CAST(COUNT(col_1) as float) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name)
```

What is the syntax I'd use to round to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Do so *after* the computation.  In most databases, this will work:

```
CAST(CAST(COUNT(col_1) as float) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name) as DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

However, many databases also support `ROUND()`:

```
ROUND(CAST(COUNT(col_1) as float) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name), 2)
```